# UML diagram java

Tags: java, arrays, uml, java.util.scanner

I'm a little confused and cannot find out how to write this in code from the UML diagram. I know it's a public class, and its first word is the method. I'm confused about the object array inside the method if it even is inside the method. Thanks for your time.

- getSize(Scanner sc) : Object[]
- friendOrFamily(Scanner sc) : int

Comment: Return type of the method. Odd that `getSize(Scanner)` would return an `Object[]`. Also odd to name the `Scanner` in UML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no array notation in UML.  But the closest thing in UML is multiplicity combined with a type name (e.g. `Object`) :

```
myarray: Object [*]                
myboundedarray: Object[2..5]
myoptional: Object [0..1]
```

This means an unlimited number of objects, a bounded list of objects between 2 and 5 elements, and an optional object that can be absent (minimum 0) or present (maximum 1).

For operations (aka methods), you just indicate it with a colon, after the parameter list:

```
getSize(sc: Scanner) : Object[*]
```

which describes an operation taking one parameter of type `Scanner` and returning a container with an undertermined number of elements of type `Object`.

Comment: You might cite the syntax on p. 115 of UML 2.5